# App deployment with Cultured Data for mobile apps

Tags: android, ios, deployment, mobile

We are developing some mobile apps for iOs and Android platforms. And our target markets are different countries. At the moment we create an app for every each market (same app with new cultured data).  This creates lots of provisioning profiles, apps , manageability issues...etc
I wonder what is the best practise for this case.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check these for help on internationalization and localization
http://developer.apple.com/internationalization/

http://www.icanlocalize.com/site/tutorials/iphone-applications-localization-guide/